# Set of all perfect squares

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have been going through Velleman's `How to prove` book and they have explained the set of all perfect squares using this set:

$S = \{ n^2 | n \in N\}$

Then it is claimed that the set `S` can also be rewritten as:

$S =\{x | \exists n \in N(x = n^2)\}$

I'm not able to understand the second form of the set `S`. In the first set, the elementhood test was $n \in N$. So any number `n` belonging to `N` will be in set `S`. But in the second form, the elementhood test is $\exists n \in N(x = n^2)$, but here there is no way of knowing about the result of the equality test $x = n^2$ because we don't have about the value of `x` yet. So how are both the set similar ?

Comment: I'm not sure your understanding of the first set is correct. It means, "take the set of all $n^2$ where $n$ is a natural number", not that any $n \in \mathbb N$ will be in $S$. It should be clear why this is the set of all perfect squares. The second form's condition is "there exists some natural number $n$ such that $x = n^2$": this exactly describes all perfect squares as well, so we just take the set of all such $x$.

Comment: Set notation is not necessarily an algorithm to compute $S$. You can use set notation to define sets which in fact are *not* computable. So you don't need to *know* the value of $x$ yet, and that is not the correct way to think about the shorthand of set notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition says this: $S$ is the set of all squares of natural numbers.

The second definition says this: $S$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x$ is the square of some natural number.

Comment: I'll let you have this one, yours had better language.